# JUnit for Spring mvc service method void return type

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit

Here is my Service class

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.integration.Message;
import org.springframework.integration.MessagingException;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class EmailService implements MessageHandler {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("receiveChannel")
    private DirectChannel messageChannel;

    private final Log logger = LogFactory
            .getLog(EmailService.class);

    public void init() {
        logger.info("initializing...");
        System.out.println("INIT");
        messageChannel.subscribe(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
         logger.info("Message: " + message);

    }
}
```

For the init I want to create a JUnit Test Case. How to write?

Here is what I have tried. But it is not working

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("classpath:webapptest")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-applicationcontext.xml"})
public class EmailServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    @Test(timeout=600000)
    public void testEmailService() throws Exception {
        emailService=Mockito.spy(emailService);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(emailService).init();
    }
}
```

In the console it is not printing the logger or print statements in the `init()` method.

What error I am doing? How to write the test case?

Answer (score 1):

In your tests you havent called `init()`. It will not execute the `Mockito.doNothing().when` without you calling the `init()` method. As far as your code is concerned, the `init()` method is just a regular public method.

If you do want the `init()` method to be called after the class is instantiated, you would have to annotate it with a [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation.

Your test should be something like this below

```
@Test(timeout=600000)
public void testEmailService() throws Exception {
.....
        emailService.init();
}
```

You would have to call `emailService.init()` since  you have created a spy; for the test to work. Currently you arent testing anything, just have a bunch of Mocks in your test method. 
Also, a comprehensive test would be where you verify if the `messageChannle.subscribe()` method is called upon testing the init method. 
You do want to tighten your test by verifying that the `subscribe()` method is called or not.

Comment: Thanks. how can I verify that?

Comment: I added the above. Still it is not printing anything

Comment: @iProgrammer Well, you told it to do nothing. Printing would be doing something, wouldn't it?

Comment: After that I am calling `emailService.init();`. So it should print right? 
When I remove `doNothing()`, it is showing error and giving option to type cast to `EmailService`

Comment: Can you put it in debug, and check if the init() method is getting executed at all? Also, you are autowiring EmailService as well as spying on it?